# How can I show the localized description of an error in an error label format to a user in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm very new to Swift, and Instead of just printing the localized description of an error when a user attempts to register for an app, I want to show it in an error label to the user. However, I get the error "Expression is not assignable: function call returns immutable value." I'm not sure what this means or what I should be doing differently in order to show the default description for the error.

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    errorLabel.isHidden = true
}


@IBAction func registerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    
    if let email = emailTextfield.text, let password = passwordTextfield.text {
    
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
     if let e = error {
        self.errorLabel.isHidden = false
        String(e.localizedDescription) = self.errorLabel.text!
        "Expression is not assignable: function call returns immutable value"

        } else {
            //Navigate to ChatViewController
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "RegisterToChat", sender: self)
        }
        
    }
    
}
}
```

}

[image: error message picture]

Comment: What's this?  String(e.localizedDescription) = self.errorLabel.text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment must be the other way round. You are going to assign always the right side to the left side.

And you don’t need to create a string from a string

```
self.errorLabel.text = e.localizedDescription
```